# I want to pass id from view to controller in Codeigniter using Ajax and Update a Dropdown Selection in DB

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I wanted to pass ID of each row from table and pass it to controller using AJAX and wanted to  update the Dropdown Selection of that row in DB.

The Selection what i make in Dropdown is passed to the controller but not sure how to update in DB based on its each row condition. A help would be much Appreciated!!!

**Below is the Screenshot of my UI**

Screen Shot with ID and Dropdown

[image: Screen Shot with ID and Dropdown]

**View File**

```
<?php if( is_array( $fbrecords ) && count( $fbrecords ) > 0 ) 
foreach($fbrecords as $r) { ?>
    <tr class="idrow">
        <td id="tdname" ><!-- style="display:none;" --> <?php echo $r->id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r->fullname; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r->email; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r->mobile; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r->message; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r->jtime; ?></td>
        <td> <?php  $data=array(
        
'name'=>'status',
'row' => '12px',
'id' => 'status',
'selected'=>'none',
'class'=>'statusClass'

);
$data_status = array(
'none' => 'none',
'A&A' => 'Attended & Acted',
'YTA' => 'Yet to Attend',
);
echo form_dropdown($data, $data_status, set_value('status')); ?> </td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success emlbtn" > Reply to <?php $fname=explode(" ",$r->fullname); echo $fname[0]; ?></button>
```

**AJAX Code**

```
$(document).ready(  function() {
$(".statusClass").change(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
//var dropDown = document.getElementById("status");
//var status =  dropDown.options[dropDown.selectedIndex].value;
var status = $(this).val(); 
console.log(status);
jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/user_authentication/user_data_status_submit",
dataType: 'json',
data: {status:status},
success: function(data){
if (result)
{
alert("success");
}
}

});
});
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function user_data_status_submit(){

$data = array(
'status' => $this->input->post('status'),
'id'
);
//Either you can print value or you can send value to database
echo json_encode($data);
$this->login_database->feedback_update($data);

}
```

**Update Function in Model**

```
public function feedback_update($data){

$this->db->set($data); 
$this->db->where("id", $old_id);
$this->db->update('feedback_table', $data);

}
```

Comment: echo the id value inside your update link. Example: `<?php echo base_url('controller/model/)'.$r->id ?>`

Comment: where in the update link. I'm Using AJAX. I want row ID to be passed when user clicks a Dropdown from a particular row and send and process it using AJAX. i'm new to this, Apologies if am not clear!!

Comment: can you post the PARSED html?

Comment: you need to put something inside the dropdown like `data-id="<?php echo $r->id  ?>"` then call it inside jquery and pass it to your ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First change your $data array() like this :**

```
 $data = array(
 'data-user' => $r->id, //ID of the row
 'name'=>'status',
 'row' => '12px',
 'id' => 'status',
 'selected'=>'none',
'class'=>'statusClass'
);
```

**Your ajax should be like this way:**

```
  $(".statusClass").each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).on('change', function(e) {
        var id = $(this).data('user');
        var status = $(this).val(); 
        console.log(id);
        console.log(status);
        // your ajax stuff go as usual
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot mate!! this actually solved but can you tell me what actually what below code does     /** .each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).on('change', function(e) { **/

Comment: .each is jquey method designed to make DOM looping  It select   particular element's attr  when we click on it  as here many dropdown have the same class name it retrieve the attr of that  dropdown to which we want to make a change.For more please see https://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 1):

Based on the question, I come up with this simple solution. To be able to get the id and pass it yo your `ajax` call, all you need is add `data-id` for example inside your `<td>` tag.

Take a closer look below

```
<td id="tdname" data-id="<?php echo $r->id ?>" ><?php echo $r->id; ?></td>
```

Now that we have the `id` value inside our data-id, we can now pass it using jquery like below

```
$(document).ready(  function() {
$(".statusClass").change(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var id = $("#tdname").data("id");
var status = $(this).val(); 
console.log(status);
jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/user_authentication/user_data_status_submit/" + id,
dataType: 'json',
data: {status:status},
success: function(data){
if (result)
{
alert("success");
}
}

});
});
});
```

Lastly, add the `$id` param inside your controller.

Comment: ya id is Showing up. But its showing the first value only i.e., 1. Any help here claudios!?

Comment: the id will loop if you have more than 1 from your db